# Keep getting relative routes in ember.js

Tags: routes, ember.js

I'm using ember-data-source (0.13), ember-rails (0.13.0), ember-source (1.0.0.rc6.2), and the emblem pre-processor.

I have this following router:

```
Whistlr.Router.map ()->
  @resource('home', path: '/');
  @resource('explore');
  @resource('organizations')
```

And these links in the header:

```
li.brand = linkTo 'home'
  = t layout.header.whistlr
li = linkTo 'explore'
  = t layout.header.explore
li = linkTo 'organizations'
  = t layout.header.organizations
```

I would expect the links to be rendered as:

```
<a href="/">Whistlr</a>
<a href="/explore">Explore</a>
<a href="/organizations">Organizations</a>
```

Instead I get:

```
<a href="#/">Whistlr</a>
<a href="#/explore">Explore</a>
<a href="#/organizations">Organizations</a>
```

Any idea what's causing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note from the [docs](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-the-location-api/):

> By default the Router uses the browser's hash to load the starting state of your application and will keep it in sync as you move around. At present, this relies on a [hashchange](http://caniuse.com/hashchange) event existing in the browser.

If you don't want this to be the default behavior you should override the default by configuring your Router with:

```
App.Router.reopen({
  location: 'none'
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I was just reading about this. The curious thing is that my links are not rendered as `/#/` but as `#/`. This means that whatever page the user starts on, such as `whistlr.org/organizations`, becomes the root for the whole app. From then on, I get links like `whistlr.org/organizations#/explore` rather than `whistlr.org/explore`. Is this intended behavior, or is something going wrong?

Comment: @timothythehuman `whistlr.org/organizations#/explore` seams odd, I guess there must be something else going wrong.

Comment: That's good to know. I'll update you if I figure out what's going on.

Comment: @timothythehuman, you could try to set the location to `history` instead of `none` maybe this helps

Comment: Looks like my organizations model had a syntax error in it. When I fixed the typo, ember started working as expected. My best guess is that ember was chocking while processing the organizations model, leading to the strange routes. Thanks for your help!